# using GNOME in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, 16.04

I have installed and used Ubuntu, and now I want to try the
GNOME desktop environment.

I don't know where to start. Could you give me some guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

## Installing Gnome-Shell

Open a terminal and first of all fetch the latest package informations via

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install gnome-shell via the following command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

If that finished, logout and back in the login-dialog (most likely lightdm) choose your session type and relogin to a new session - this time using Gnome.
[image]

You'll find some documentation for the gnome project [here](https://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/).

Comment: The package is called `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` on 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @Videonauth: fixed it

Comment: Please mark the thread as solved then & enjoy Gnome. Have fun ;)

Comment: No, there is no such button at least on 16.04, which is what the original poster is using.

Comment: @dufte I have installed `gnome-shell` by following the above, but how do I update it?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya - updates are handled like for any other package installed via apt. So running ´sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade´ should result in installing all available updates for your situation.

Comment: @NoBugs are you talking about the selection in LightDM?

Comment: @dufte There was no selector that I saw in standard Ubuntu login screen.

Comment: @NoBugs The screenshot above shows the selection in LightDM which is afaik the default in 16.04

Answer (score 8):

Go to the terminal and type this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Logoff, then select the Gnome Desktop at the login screen.