# Trying to install Gnome-Shell

Tags: apt, gnome

I was following this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/781562/846903) on how to install gnome, but after I run the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

I get the following messages

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: gnome-photos but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libreoffice-style-tango but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Do you have a graphic display at the moment? And if so, is it X or Wayland?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `-f` option at the time to install to fix broken packages or dependencies:

```
apt -f install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

You can try to search for the correct package of gnome for your current distribution:

```
apt-cache search gnome-desktop
```